# Rejected binary due to data storage issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My application has been rejected due to this problem :

[image]

Comment: how many bytes you want to store in the cloud? what does your data contain that you want to store 27 MB?

Comment: Nothing !! this is a dictionary application and I don't use any iCloud options

Comment: so your dictionary is about 27mb. it is somehow  interpreted as user data. other users will suggest how to exclude that. i have not worked with cloud feature yet. maybe the db has to be in an separte folder, where it is not interpreted as user data. you should read more about directory structure, and cloud service.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12371323/1633251

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10786416/147037 also seems to be on point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `NSDocumentDirectory` to `NSCachesDirectory` and finally approved !